# UnboundLocalError running .py from .bat (with API); Runs fine in Command Prompt

Tags: python, batch-file

When I execute my commands in the Command Prompt on Windows 10 Python 3.8.2, I get the expected behavior and my data saves as it should (1.0.3 printed for troubleshooting):

```
    Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.746]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users>SET BEARER_TOKEN=xyz

C:\Users>cd C:\Users\TwitterConv

C:\Users\TwitterConv>python scrape-test.py neonphotography
1.0.3

C:\Users\TwitterConv>
```

However when I put this into a .bat file I get the following error when running it from anywhere:

```
C:\Users\TwitterConv>python scrape-test.py neonphotography
1.0.3
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "scrape-test.py", line 333, in <module>
        main()
      File "scrape-test.py", line 322, in main
        user_ids = get_user_info(headers, filename)
      File "scrape-test.py", line 155, in get_user_info
        user_df = pandas.json_normalize(json_response["data"])
    UnboundLocalError: local variable 'json_response' referenced before assignment
```

Here is the .bat file:

```
SET BEARER_TOKEN=xyz
cd /D C:\Users\TwitterConv
python scrape-test.py neonphotography
```

I'm trying to adapt this project from coworkers using Mac's and I really expected this to be easy once I started reading about batch files. I've tried using pyinstaller as a work around but that's a whole new set of issues, so I figured I would start here.

Why is my batch file not running properly?

Comment: You are missing the `CD` command in your batch file.  You will also probably want to use the `/D` option with the `CD` command just in case the work directory is a different drive letter.

Comment: That was just a typo. The .bat file was in the destination folder so I don't even need to set the directory to access the file. But I  moved the .bat file and made sure to fix the `CD` and the issue persists.

When I used `/D` I got the `/D is not recognized` error. 

Thanks for the feedback. I will fix the examples.

Comment: `cd /D C:\Users\TwitterConv` will not cause that error.

Comment: You are right. But the issue persists with the correct syntax. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's useful to look at the stack trace itself.  The only way your script can fail like that is if the call to twitter is failing.  In this case, the only thing that could reasonably differ with the batch file versus the interactive command line is somehow the bearer token is different.  Since bearer tokens often have percent symbols in them, there's probably something going on there.

We can simplify this with a simple script:

```python
# This is example.py
import os
print("BEARER_TOKEN=[" + os.environ.get("BEARER_TOKEN") + "]")
```

If you run this interactively, it works as you'd expect:

```
C:\Example>set BEARER_TOKEN=this%is%an%example%token

C:\Example>python example.py
BEARER_TOKEN=[this%is%an%example%token]
```

However, running it with a simple batch file, it will not work as expected:

```
@echo off
rem This is example.cmd
set BEARER_TOKEN=this%is%an%example%token
python3 example.py
```

```
C:\Example>example.cmd
BEARER_TOKEN=[thisantoken]
```

You'll need to escape the percent symbols in your batch file, since they're parsed differently than the interactive prompt:

```
@echo off
rem This is the fixed example.cmd
set BEARER_TOKEN=this%%is%%an%%example%%token
python3 example.py
```

```
C:\Example>example.cmd
BEARER_TOKEN=[this%is%an%example%token]
```

Comment: Wow. That did it! Thank you so much for your help. I spent hours sifting through stackoverflow trying to understand what was going wrong. I'm going to remove my .py file now.

Comment: @Domlock, this is why people are asked when they signup at StackOverFlow to read the [Tour]. Learn [ask] a question.  And provide a [mcve].  In your case you never provided a reproducible example.  And because this question solved your problem you now get to read. [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)